# Copy values between variables in bash script

Tags: bash

How can I copy the numeric value in a variable to another variable in bash script. If this were C, I would do

```
int a=0;
int b;
a=b;
```

I am trying to do this:

```
if [ $countip -gt $totalip ]; 
then
    $countip -eq $srctip # <-- My problem is here!
    echo $srctip
fi
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just say

```
countip=$srctip
```

This is how assignment works in bash. This will set countip to the value of srctip. If you
want to assign srctip then just write

```
srctip=$countip
```

Based on the comments below this looks like the one you want.

Comment: Thanks for replying, i`m obtaining allways 0 in $srctip.

Comment: @gomesg are you trying to assign to `srctip`? Reverse the variables: `srctip=$countip`.

Comment: I`m trying to get the highest value of countip and copy it to $srctip. This is what iàm trying to do do. I am sory i am new to bash script. I was for the last 15 years a telecom tec and now i have to admin an entire linux based lan!

Comment: for srcip in `cat /var/log/messages | grep "WACSLAW1 CRITICAL INCOMING" | awk '{ print $14 }'|grep -v 192.168.1. |grep -v IN=eth1 |grep -v MAC`;do

        if (! grep "$srcip" /var/wacstemp/ids.tmp > /dev/null) ; then
                countip=0
                echo $srcip >> /var/wacstemp/ids.tmp
        else
                countip=`expr $countip + 1`

                        if [ $countip -gt $totalip ];
                        then
                                countip=$srctip
                                echo $srctip
                        fi
        fi

Comment: Might be better to update your original post if the problem hasn't been solved yet.