# Assigning one variable to another in Bash?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a doubt. When i declare a value and assign to some variable, I don't know how to reassign the same value to another variable. See the code snippet below.

```
#/bin/sh    
#declare ARG1 to a
a=ARG1
#declaring $a to ARG2    
ARG2=$`$a`

echo "ARG 2 = $ARG2"
```

It should display my output as

```
ARG 2 = ARG1
```

...but instead the actual output is:

```
line 5: ARG1: command not found
ARG 2 = $
```

Comment: I edited the title, as the question doesn't appear to have anything to do with declaring variables. (Variables _can_ be declared in shell, but this is necessary to explicitly set types or scope metadata, rather than to assign values).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy values between variables in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15094968/608639)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To assign the value associated with the variable `dest` to the variable `source`, you need simply run `dest=$source`.

For example, to assign the value associated with the variable `arg2` to the variable `a`:

```
a=ARG1
arg2=$a
echo "ARG 2 = $arg2"
```

The use of lower-case variable names for local shell variables is by convention, not necessity -- but this has the advantage of avoiding conflicts with environment variables and builtins, both of which use all-uppercase names by convention.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You got it right. Even i thought is that this much simple. But my i am posting my script here. Help me out here..

Comment: @NarayanamurthyBalasubramanian, I would hope that comparing what I'm doing against your script would be enough to make it clear: Change the line assigning ARG2 to `ARG2=$a` -- no extra unnecessary syntax. If this still doesn't answer your question, please clarify what you need to know.

Comment: I have changed my question and added few script lines. Help me out on this.

Comment: Changing your question after a correct answer is given is not kosher. You should ask a new question in this case.

Comment: No worries. Please try to follow the guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve when constructing that question.

Comment: @F8ER, correct, but as arrays need a different syntax that's best asked as a separate question.

Comment: also: bash cares about spaces arg2=$a works arg2 = $a will fail

Comment: @joseph_morris, obviously. What does that have to do with this answer? `ARG 2 = value` is the **output format** the question is asking for. It's not part of the code that we're running; instead, it's output the code is responsible for printing.

Answer (score 4):

You may also want to **alias** rather than **copy** the variable. For example, if you need mutation. Or if you want to run a function multiple times on different variables. Here's how it works

Example:

```bash
C=cat
declare -n VAR=C
VAR+=" says Hi"
echo "$C"  # prints "cat says Hi"
```

Example with arrays/dictionaries:

```bash
A=(a a a)
declare -n VAR=A  # "-n" stands for "name", e.g. a new name for the same variable
VAR+=(b)
echo "${A[@]}"  # prints "a a a b"
```

That is, `VAR` becomes effectively **the same** as the original variable. Instead of **copying**, you're adding an **alias**. Here's an example with functions:

```bash
function myFunc() {
  local -n VAR="$1"
  VAR="Hello from $2"
  echo "I've set variable '$1' to value '$VAR'"
}
myFunc Inbox Bob  # I've set variable 'Inbox' to value 'Hello from Bob'
myFunc Luke Leia  # I've set variable 'Luke' to value 'Hello from Leia'
echo "$Luke"  # Hello from Leia
```

Whether you should use these approaches is a question. Generally, immutable code is easier to read and to reason about (in almost any programming language). However, sometimes you really need to get stuff done in a certain way. Hope this answer helps you then.